# Destroyed civilization, dictionary as book of names

Tags: story-identification

This has been bugging me for 20+ years.. I read a book in 5th grade about a small colony that survived some kind of destruction.. And one of the only books they had was a dictionary, and they used that to name people (the beginning pages - with prefixes. Any ideas?!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Also, what kind of colony and destruction was it? As it's written right now, it's not entirely clear that the book (it's a book, right?) you're looking for is science-fiction or fantasy. It probably is, but more defining elements would help tracking it down

Answer (score 4):

This sounds to me like "Dawn in Andromeda" (1956) by E.C. Large.

God puts five men and five women on an island with the task of building a radio from scratch. They take names from the Encyclopaedia Brittanica.

A post on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16229199-dawn-in-andromeda) says " they gave themselves names, which one of them had seen on an encyclopaedia set. It was actually an issue of the Encyclopaedia Britannica. The names I can remember are Men: Game Gun, Nab Ozon, Sars Sorc and Sort Text, and Women: Annu Balt, Cole Dama and Vase Zygo"